# Default category got deleted. How to get it back as ID=1?

Tags: plugin-development

I have a plugin that expects there to be a default "uncategorized" category with ID=1. I've inadvertantly deleted the uncategorized category. Is it possible to recreate the category as ID=1?

When I look at a default WP install, I see that the table "wp_terms" has uncategorized as the first record with id 1. It also appears that the "wp_term_relationships" and "wp_term_taxonomy" tables are in play in this regard.

How would one go about recreating this category?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need 3 steps:

1.Creating  a term in wp_terms with ID is 1

2.Insert a term_taxanomy into wp_term_taxonomy with term_id is 1, and taxonomy must be category

3.Insert a term_relationships into wp_term_relationships with object_id is 1 and term_taxonomy_id is 1
Run below code in PHPMYADMIN to re-create this category!

```
INSERT INTO wp_terms (term_id, `name`, slug) VALUES (1, 'Uncategorized', 'uncategorized');
INSERT INTO wp_term_taxonomy (term_taxonomy_id, term_id, taxonomy, parent) VALUES (1, 1, 'category', 0);
INSERT INTO wp_term_relationships (object_id, term_taxonomy_id, term_order) VALUES (1, 1, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for. In this case, it will be a one off to fix this website. Can I call these inserts directly from my plugin script or do I need to establish a connection to wpdb global?

Comment: You can run it directly on PHPMYADMIN! Or use global $wpdb object and call query method: $wpdb->query()

Answer (score 6):

Could your plugin not use `get_option('default_category')`, which returns the ID of the default category?

Comment: **To compliment this answer:** If a plugin maintained by someone else is hard-coding this value and it's part of a callback function, you can always unhook that callback and replace it with your own copy until such time the plugin is coded better.

Answer (score 2):

It's an auto incrementing integer, so you can't using WP. But you can edit the term id and its taxonomy id from the database directly.

Comment: `INSERT INTO wp_terms (term_id, name, slug) VALUES (1, 'Uncategorized', 'uncategorized')`. Sometimes it's not feasible to update the existing code, whether or not it's the "right" thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Either recreate it directly in the database by copying another one in and editing it, OR, why not check in your plugin files?  Just do a file search for the id=1 thing and see what you come up with, and then change that to your new default id #.  I always find it's easier to edit plugin and php files than mucking around in the database.

Comment: I kinda (sorta) like the first part of this answer, but not so much the second part because any update to the plugin is going to re-break the site. The best solution would be for the plugin to allow *setting* the default category as opposed to making the completely arbitrary decision that it's the first one you thought to create. But that means getting the plugin author to fix it ... not always an easy thing to do.

Comment: Peter, I agree.  I should have mentioned that in my post.  It would have been nice for the plugin to have given that option, but it's still a viable option for the user so long as they're aware that any future updates would possibly break it.  Sometimes it's worth making a change like that.  The OP has to weigh that in his decision.